# Is "proven" very old -fashioned?

Tags: word-choice, past-participles, historical-change, variants, contemporary-english

I occasionally see the participle "proven" in mathematical texts, instead of "proved".
Of course I realize that this a deliberate archaism, but I wanted to know if this is still used in books or articles in the USA, and whether  a young American  would find the  form *proven* odd in 2012.

(I'm asking because I have a not completely finished project for an article that would end with: *we have thus proven that the zeros of the zeta function are on the line...*)

Comment: While I can't specifically comment on Americans, it certainly appears from context that you are using the word in a mathematical or scientific context, where it would not be out of place in modern usage.

If you wanted to avoid the word, you could use "demonstrated" instead.

Comment: When caught making mischief, every American schoolchild will declare s/he is "innocent until proven guilty," so even if "proven" has fallen out of use in specific contexts, it is far from foreign to any generation.

Comment: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prove?q=proven (scroll down a bit)

Comment: I haven't supplied an answer, because you specifically asked about American English; and I am not an expert in American English. However, it may well be a regionalism. For me, "proven" is the correct past participle - I would never say "we have proved". If you're worried about your last sentence sounding archaic, you should do something about the "thus", not about the "proven".

Comment: That's interesting David: may I be so bold as to ask you where you are from? (Incidentally, I'm not worried at all about sounding archaic: I rather like the idea! I am just interested in the way Americans speak or write English)

Comment: MW (AmE): "Surveys made some 50 or 60 years ago indicated that proved was about four times as frequent as proven. But our evidence from the last 30 or 35 years shows this no longer to be the case. As a past participle proven is now about as frequent as proved in all contexts." That's re: your "archaism". http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proven

Comment: @Christi: thanks for your comment. As I told David, I don't want to avoid  archaic words: I am just curious. And I don't like *demonstrate* because it sounds less English and too Gallic ( to my French ears!)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Fair enough, but you do know that large chunks of English have their origins in medieval French?  We foolishly got conquered by the Duke of Normandy, and the language never really recovered. :)

Comment: Since you asked whether a young American would find it odd, and I'm a young (college-aged) American (who takes plenty of math classes), I'll chime in and say that no, it doesn't sound odd at all to me.

Comment: Dear @Christi: yes, I knew that. But now Alex is telling us that also proved/proven are of  French origin! So much for my sensitive ears that want to hear real Germanic/Saxon/Norse English...

Comment: @Cameron: thank you for your answer, *young* man. And I hope I will soon hear from you on math.stackexchange, since you already have an account there.....

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg You may certainly ask where I am from.  Or you can click my name in the comment, and read for yourself that I have lived my entire life in New Zealand.

Comment: @David: Ah, yes, I should have clicked instead of bothering you. Anyway, thanks for the information.

Comment: An article in preparation that ends with "we have thus proven that the zeros of the zeta function are on the line..." sounds potentially very important if you can just fill in that "..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some folks use *proven* in both the past participle and adjective alike, while others reserve that form to adjectival use and instead use *proved* only as the verb. Here’s such a distinction:

- He hadn’t yet proved it.
- Is that a proven fact?

I don’t think that either would raise an eyebrow.  Or rather, you could alternately use *proven* in the first case above, but you could **not** use *proved* in the second one.  At least, that’s what my ear tells me.

Also, I believe the verdict in Scots law is *not proven*, not *not proved*.

---

### Edit

As of 2007, the *OED3* reports of [**proven** *adj.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/153407):

> This is the usual form in Scottish English (as opposed to **proved** *adj*.), and also the preferred form in current North American English. It is now also more frequent than **proved** *adj*.   in British English.

Its tale under [**prove** *v.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/153398) is ***much, much*** longer; I can give only an excerpt here.

> **Pronunciation**: Brit.  `/pruːv/`, U.S.  `/pruv/` 
>   **Inflections**:  Past participle **proved**, **proven**.
>
> The past participle **proven**, originally Scots and the usual form in Scottish English, developed from the β forms by analogy with strong verbs like **cloven**, past participle of **cleave** *v.<sup>1</sup>*, **woven**, past participle of **weave** *v.<sup>1</sup>*   It is at least as common as **proved** in current North American English. It is also spreading into other varieties of English, in which the highest proportion of occurrences appears to occur in the past and perfect passive. Compare **proven** *adj*., **proved** *adj*.

So I really do not think that *proven* should be considered a deliberate archaism, insofar as in some parts of English it has always had a strong presence, and it seems now to be spreading even to regions where it previously did not hold sway.  At least that’s my reading of the OED note above.

Comment: Thanks @tchrist: nice to find you here too. And +1, of course.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg You’re welcome. And did you already know I was (something of) a francophone, or was yesterday’s comment just a random stab in the dark?

Comment: Dear @tchrist,  no, I had no idea: *le monde est petit!* By the way, I have just erased two  of my comments about the plural of family names in *-y*: they were clearly the result of a misunderstanding!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Check out my OED additions to my answer.  On languages, I’m fluent in Spanish (have lived and worked in Spain, have a degree in Spanish), and studied French as my obligatory 3rd language. I’ve briefly worked in France, Belgium, la Suisse Romande, and Québec, but never lived there so haven’t really ever gotten the fluency up.

Comment: Dear @tchrist, I'm going from surprise to surprise: not only is *proven* not archaic, but it is spreading! (And, on a more personal level, for what was French obligatory?)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg It was obligatory to study a third language; I chose French.

Answer (score 7):

**proved, proven.** (copypasted)

"The two forms relate to two different verbs derived from Old French prover (ultimately from Latin probare). **In standard BrE, proved is the normal past tense and past participle of the verb prove** (*They proved their point / Their point was proved*). *Proven* survived as a past participle in dialect use and is current in the Scottish legal term *not proven* (usually pronounced proh-ven) and occasionally in general use in Britain generally (pronounced proo-ven), especially in attributive position (i.e. before a noun):

*His love of precise dates and proven facts*—N. Shakespeare, 1989.

**In AmE, proven is at least as common as proved both as a past tense ***[? - Alex B.]***and as a past participle.**"

"proved"  Pocket Fowler's Modern English Usage. Ed. Robert Allen. Oxford University Press, 2008. Oxford Reference Online. Oxford University Press.

Comment: +1 for source, and also for the "not proven" point, which I was itching to make.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alex: I would never  have guessed that *proven* is at least as common as *proved* in the USA.

Comment: I don't believe that *proven* is at all common as a past tense; *"I proven the theorem yesterday"* sounds completely wrong. As a past participle, though, it seems tied with *proved* right now; [see Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+proved%2Chas+proven%2C+it+proved%2C+it+proven&year_start=1800&year_end=2005&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20proved%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20proven%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20proved%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20proven%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor, I myself am quite baffled as to how to interpret that statement - hence a question mark in brackets [? - Alex B.].